# Is there any unclick event in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to style my `div` using jquery, i want to make it when i click the background become blue, when i unclick(i clicked on other part other than div in my page) the background become red. Sorry for my bad english

Comment: unclick = click outside of a specific element after a click into it?

Comment: Yes, it's called `off()`, but that's not what you are looking for, you're looking for a simple toggle function (jQuery's toggle is deprecated btw) on the document, checking the target etc. There must be at least thousands of duplicates of this ?

Comment: There's no such event but you could capture clicks to the `document` and add some logic.

Comment: @Jan Dvorak If I capture click to the document it also affect my div, because my div is inside my document

Comment: you want to color the background of your div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a click handler on `document` you can capture all the click events, and if the click is not on your div, you can revert to red

```
$('#yourdiv').click(function() {
   $(this).css('background-color', 'blue');
});

$(document).click(function(e) {
   if(!$(e.target).is('#yourdiv'))
      $('#yourdiv').css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

See example: http://jsbin.com/oyunin/1/edit

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure about performace, but you can do something like:

```
    $("*").not("your element selector").on("click",function(){
         //other elements click
      });
```

a good practice will be doing this:

$("*","some container").not......

Comment: You also have to exclude all parents of the element due to event bubbling.

Comment: @JanDvorak Or stop the event bubbling when you click on that element.

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved it in my site was adding a `click` event to the `div` in question, and another `click` event to the document in general. The method `stopImmediatePropagation()` makes it work as expected:

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/napascual/xMNnF/1/) with a working example.

HTML:

```
<div class="colored"></div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(document).click(function(e){
    $(".active").removeClass("active");
});

$(".colored").live("click",function(e){
    $(this).addClass("active");
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

CSS:

```
.colored{background:red}
.colored.active{background:blue}
```

Comment: @JanDvorak I already fixed the answer, now it works as expected, thanks for correcting me

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change the div when you click on another div, you can add a click event on the other div, or perhaps you want to add the click event to the entire body of the document so that if a click event is not captured and stopped by another listener, it will go through to the body's event listener.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

**Jquery Code:**

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e){
    var wrapDiv = $(".wrapper");
    if(wrapDiv.has(e.target).length === 0){
        wrapDiv.css('background-color','red');
    }
    $('.wrapper').click(function(event){
       $('.wrapper').css('background-color','blue')
    });
});
```

**CSS code:**

```
<style type="text/css">
.wrapper{
    background-color:#0FF;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    }
</style>
```

**Html code:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
</div>
```